# Duplicate entries on infinite loader and filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using the vue-infinite-loader to display user and load them on scroll. In addition, I have a filter by name.

I followed the instructions given at https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/guide/use-with-filter-or-tabs.html

Here is the HTML for the filter:

```
 <input v-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name" @input="changeName">
```

And here the relevant vue methods:

```
 methods: {
        infiniteHandler: function ($state) {
            console.log(api + this.parameter);
            axios.get(api + this.parameter, {params: {page: this.page}}).then((result) =>   {
                if (result.data.meta.current_page <= result.data.meta.last_page) {
                    this.page += 1;
                    this.users.push(...result.data.data);

                    $state.loaded();
                } else {
                    $state.complete();
                }
            });
        },
        changeName() {
             this.parameter= '?name=' + encodeURIComponent(this.name);
             this.page = 1;
             this.users = [];
             this.infiniteId += 1;                          
        },
```

If I enter now quickly "Max" as username in the input textfiled, then `changeName` is executed 3 times, one time with `M`, `Ma` and `Max`. The problem is, that the calls are in parallel, meaning users starting with `Max` will also match to start with `Ma` and `M`. Thus I suddenly have duplicates and also user with names that don't start with `Max` but with `Marjon` etc.

I actually have inside `changeName()` a timeout, to prevent a HTTP call on every keystroke:

```
 changeName() {            
     clearTimeout(this.timeout);
     this.timeout = setTimeout(function() { ...}, 200);
 },
```

However the theoretical problem from above is still possible to happen here (if keystrokes and HTTPS calls both take longer then 200ms).

I would like then if the user enters "Ma" and then "Max" that the axios call triggered by "Ma" is stopped and immediately the call for "Max" is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel axios requests you can use the [canceltoken](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

Note how any previous request is cancelled when you call `infiniteHandler` - and that the cancel token is removed when the request finishes

Thus, no extra code, other than the few lines here, is needed

```
methods: {
    infiniteHandler: function ($state) {
        console.log(api + this.parameter);
        // _cancelSource is truthy if there's a request "in flight"
        if (this._cancelSource) {
            this._cancelSource.cancel('new search');
            this._cancelSource = null;
        }
        // get a new canceToken
        this._cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
        axios.get(api + this.parameter, {
            cancelToken: this._cancelSource.token
            params: {page: this.page}
        }).then((result) =>   {
            // no need to cancel now
            this._cancelSource = null;
            if (result.data.meta.current_page <= result.data.meta.last_page) {
                this.page += 1;
                this.users.push(...result.data.data);
                $state.loaded();
            } else {
                $state.complete();
            }
        });
    },
```

In case the cancellation doesn't quite work - you can chain the promises returned by axios

However, I don't believe this would be required

May still be useful if you don't want to cancel the previous request (for some other purpose) by removing the cancelToken code

```
methods: {
    infiniteHandler: function ($state) {
        console.log(api + this.parameter);
        
        // initialise the promise for first time
        this._requestPromise = this._requestPromise || Promise.resolve();
        
        // _cancelSource is truthy if there's a request "in flight"
        if (this._cancelSource) {
            this._cancelSource.cancel('new search');
            this._cancelSource = null;
        }
        // get a new canceToken
        this._cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
        
        // chain on to the previous request
        // NOTE: cancelling the previous request will make it reject ... 
        //      but that can be handled
        this._requestPromise = this._requestPromise
         // handle any cancelled previous request
         // or previous request rejections
         // we still want to do this one if the previous rejected
        .catch(() => {}) 
        .then(() => {
            axios.get(api + this.parameter, {
                cancelToken: this._cancelSource.token
                params: {page: this.page}
            }).then((result) =>   {
                // no need to cancel now
                this._cancelSource = null;
                if (result.data.meta.current_page <= result.data.meta.last_page) {
                    this.page += 1;
                    this.users.push(...result.data.data);
                    $state.loaded();
                } else {
                    $state.complete();
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel an axios request right before another starts using axios' [CancelToken](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get(api + this.parameter, {
    params: {page: this.page}},
    cancelToken: source.token
).then((result) =>   {
    if (result.data.meta.current_page <= result.data.meta.last_page) {
        this.page += 1;
        this.users.push(...result.data.data);
        $state.loaded();
    } else {
        $state.complete();
    }
});
```

(Code not tested, but gives the idea)